# How to highlight a row and force row/cell refresh in a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

This is my first question on SOF, so please be gentle on me :)

I have a simple WPF DataGrid defined in XAML. The application loads "user" data (FirstName, LastName) into the grid from a text file, and after loading the entries from a text file, the user hit the submit button, I want to iterate over the items in the list and submit each row to a webservice that creates Users and then display the reply from the webservice in the grid.

In order to keep the user informed, I want to somehow highlight the current row being submitted, and I want the message to appear immediatly after the response is received. If the message is an error, highlight the row in red, if success, highlight it in green.

Seems simple enough...

I have a simple GridDto class that represents the Data to map to each row. It implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. For simplicity sake, I define it as following:

```
class GridDto : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  private string Reply;
  public string Reply
  {
      get
      {
        return this.message;
      }
      set
      {
          this.message = value;
          this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Reply"));
      }
   }
```

The grid accepts a list of FirstName and LastNames from a text file.

The way I populate this grid is to build a collection of `ObservableCollection<GridDto>` and then I do:

```
resultGrid.ItemsSource = ConvertTextDtoToGridDtos(result.Elements);
```

So far so good. Now I want to submit each of the rows of my grid to a webservice that create Users. The only parameters the websrvice requires is FirstName and LastName.

Since I am new to WPF, I have no idea on how to do that. Here is what I did so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultGrid.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
    var dto = (GridDto)this.resultGrid.Items[i];
    var color = Color.FromRgb(192, 192, 25);
    try{
       // Do webservice call using the dto data
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
      dto.Reply = ex.Message;
      color = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);
    }

  DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)resultGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
  row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color) { Opacity = 0.45 };
}
```

This somewhat works, but doesn't highlight the row being treated currently.

I tried adding the following in my loop

```
resultGrid.SelectedIndex = i;
```

Or...

```
resultGrid.SelectedItem = resultGrid.Items[i];
resultGrid.ScrollIntoView(resultGrid.Items[i]);
```

And only the last row is highlighted at the end of the loop, when everything seems to be updated.

The other problem with this code is that the Reply column only gets refreshed at the end, after all the rows have been submitted, so there is no realtime informing the user.

**How do I highlight in a smart way the row currently treated, and most importantly, how do I update the reply cell after every reply, and before processing the next row.**

Thanks for your help, and sorry for my long question.

Edit: if there is a better way of doing this all together, I am opened for suggestions.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The backgroundworker is actually made for WinForms and not meant for WPF but it would work too, However I like `Action` better.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can bind bacgroundcolor to a property in style by placing this code to your XAML in `DataGrid` block

```
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Color}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

if you want to refresh UI on realtime you must use backgroud worker for submiting users

```
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs we)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < resultGrid.Items.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    var dto = (GridDto)this.resultGrid.Items[i];
                    var color = Color.FromRgb(192, 192, 25);
                    try
                    {
                        // Do webservice call using the dto data
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        dto.Reply = ex.Message;
                        color = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);
                    }
                    dto.Color = new SolidColorBrush(color) { Opacity = 0.45 };
                }
            };
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Kara. So I thought WPF would run on it's own thread for some reason. I tried the proposed code, and stripped all code beside minimal code in loop to change the color, and I get an "ArgumentException was unhandled". "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject."

Comment: I fixed the code by adding: dto.Color.Freeze(); after I set the color. But now I have an issue where I cannot do resultGrid.SelectedIndex = i; in my for loop in order to visually "select" the item before submitting it. Not that it is an asbolute necessaty, but a nice to have.
Also, since I added the color propery in my GridDto, I now see it as a column in my grid :/
Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyJordan You have two options for Columns in a DataGrid. 1. manually and 2. When `AutoGenerateColumns == true` you will have to Do something with the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn.aspx  I almost always Create them manually in xaml, except when I have the data changing to different types.

Comment: @Jeremy **BackgroudWorker** runs on another thread and UI thread cannot access SolidColorBush object which created by another thread so we must create SolidColorBrush on UI thread. for this replace `dto.Color = new SolidColorBrush(color) { Opacity = 0.45 };` line to `Dispatcher.Invoke(new VoidDelegate(delegate() { dto.Color = new SolidColorBrush(color) { Opacity = 0.45 }; }));`. and you must declare **VoidDelegate** as `public delegate void VoidDelegate();`

Answer (score 0):

This could be an option:

Add the following to `GridDto`

```
private Brush validationBrush = Brushes.White;

public Brush ValidationBrush
{
  get { return validationBrush; }
  set
  {
    validationBrush = value;
     this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValidationBrush"));
  }
}
```

And this to within your DataGrid Tag in Xaml

```
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=ValidationBrush}"/>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Updating the ValidationBrush on a `GridDto` item will change the `RowColor`

**Edit**

Could this be usefull:

```
var MyGridDtoCollection = ConvertTextDtoToGridDtos(result.Elements);
resultGrid.ItemsSource = MyGridDtoCollection;

Action a = ( ) =>
{
  foreach ( var gridDto in MyGridDtoCollection )
  {
    gridDto.ValidationBrush = Brushes.Black;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( 500 );
  }
};
a.BeginInvoke( result =>
{
  a.EndInvoke( result );
} , null );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Silvermind.
I tried the code, but I still get the same result. The dataGrid is updated visually only after I process all rows.

So if I put a Thread.Sleep() at the end of my loop, I don't see the row background change before the next row.